# Tips for keeping lots of cables tidy

Tags: wire

I'm working on a project with a lot of external peripherals, so this means lots of wires. Any recommendations on how to keep them tidy while working on it? I don't want to use cable ties just yet, as I need to keep moving them so would have to keep cutting the cable ties.

Comment: Ok @Dean, now it's a community wiki

Answer (score 14):

I like to use [Velcro Cable ties](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=velcro+cable+ties&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=1877353722848648657&sa=X&ei=lyVxTcKbJ8H7lwe12e2YCQ&ved=0CD8Q8gIwAw#). Basically used the same way as ones you would have to cut, but instead you just have to pull them apart.

Depending on what you are doing a [Wire Duct](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=wire+duct#q=wire+duct&hl=en&prmd=ivns&source=univ&tbs=shop:1&tbo=u&ei=_CVxTaDJD8GAlAfwjJ2FAQ&sa=X&oi=product_result_group&ct=image&resnum=3&ved=0CE0QzAMwAg&biw=1600&bih=1115&bav=on.2,or.&fp=4e757515720d3dfe) might benefit you more. They tend to get more messy on the inside, but can produce neater results on the outside.

Answer (score 8):

- "flexible plastic conduit"
- "corrugated flex tubing"
- "split loom"

I'm having trouble finding a good search term for it, but I've used flexible plastic/PVC wire conduit to bundle wires together in text fixtures outside of enclosures.  The stuff is commonly used in wire harnesses, especially in automotive.

It's essentially a thin, corrugated plastic hose with a slit running through it so you can shove in or pull out cables and wires, available in a wide range of sizes, from about 1/4" (almost pointless; fits about (3) 16-AWG wires) up to 2".

[image]

Comment: I've used this for a variety of projects and it looks good and is easy to use.

Comment: The 1/4" tubing is awesome for about 8x 22AWG wires.  They tend to make it into hobby projects though, since there aren't (or shouldn't be) any 22AWG mains plugs.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure where you can get it, but I've encountered this stuff that looks like spirally-cut polyethylene tubing. The stuff I've seen comes on a big reel, and you cut off as much or as little as you need. So you lop off a few inches of it, and then wind it around the wires/cables you want to bundle. It's very quick to put to use, it's quick to take off, it's re-usable, and it's neat, too.

Comment: Is this the thing you mean? http://www.maplin.co.uk/spiral-cable-wrap-26849 BTW i live in the UK and have a maplin local.

Comment: @Dean - yes, if that isn't the actual same stuff, it is certainly the same concept.

Answer (score 3):

Using twist ties to shorthen cables is a very simple first step, gets rid of long lengths of cable waiting to get tangled.

Answer (score 2):

Insulation tape... cheap, firm hold, easy to remove.

Comment: It looks a tad on the messy and unprofessional side though. But still good.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what this is called, but I think this would help.[image]
[image]